# File handling in Python

Tags: python

Im a python noob and I'm stuck on a problem.

```
filehandler = open("data.txt", "r")                                                       

alist = filehandler.readlines()                                                           

def insertionSort(alist):                                                                 

    for line in alist:                                                                    

        line = list(map(int, line.split()))                                               
        print(line)                                                                       

        for index in range(2, len(line)):                                                 

         currentvalue = line[index]                                                       
         position = index                                                                 


         while position>1 and line[position-1]>currentvalue:                              
             line[position]=line[position-1]                                              
             position = position-1                                                        

         line[position]=currentvalue                                                      

        print(line)                                                                       

insertionSort(alist)                                                                      


for line in alist:                                                                        
    print line
```

Output:

```
[4, 19, 2, 5, 11]
[4, 2, 5, 11, 19]
[8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
[8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
4 19 2 5 11

8 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2
```

I am supposed to sort lines of values from a file. The first value in the line represents the number of values to be sorted. I am supposed to display the values in the file in sorted order.

The print calls in insertionSort are just for debugging purposes.

The top four lines of output show that the insertion sort seems to be working. I can't figure out why when I print the lists after calling insertionSort the values are not sorted.

I am new to Stack Overflow and Python so please let me know if this question is misplaced.

Comment: if i understood your problem you're wondering why the lines in the file didn't change ? you mean you want to sort the values inside the file ? i'm sorry i'm a bit confused, try to explain a bit further please

Comment: You're sorting the list that you create from splitting the line. You're not changing `line` or `alist` when you do this.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a hw question? but if not, you can always use the `sorted` function

Comment: Yes it is a HW question for an algorithms class. @Barmar Im not sure how to sort the file as a list without splitting up the lines. when the '\n' character is reached it breaks the algorithm. I get this error when I set line[position] = current value  if I haven't split the lines in the file. TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in alist:                                                                    
    line = list(map(int, line.split()))
```

`line` starts out as eg `"4 19 2 5 11"`. You split it and convert to int, ie `[4, 19, 2, 5, 11]`.

You then assign this new value to `list` - but `list` is a local variable, the new value never gets stored back into `alist`.

Also, `list` is a terrible variable name because there is already a `list` data-type (and the variable name will keep you from being able to use the data-type).

Let's reorganize your program:

```
def load_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        # -> list of list of int
        data = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in inf]
    return data

def insertion_sort(row):
    # `row` is a list of int
    #
    # your sorting code goes here
    #
    return row

def save_file(fname, data):
    with open(fname, "w") as outf:
        # list of list of int -> list of str
        lines = [" ".join(str(i) for i in row) for row in data]
        outf.write("\n".join(lines))

def main():
    data = load_file("data.txt")
    data = [insertion_sort(row) for row in data]
    save_file("sorted_data.txt", data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Actually, with your data - where the first number in each row isn't actually data to sort - you would be better to do

```
    data = [row[:1] + insertion_sort(row[1:]) for row in data]
```

so that the logic of `insertion_sort` is cleaner.

Comment: For a noob, not explaining what map is doing probably doesn't help them much unless they're just looking for someone else to code for them.

Comment: I understand what map does. Having said that i am still a major noob. First time even looking at python today.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar mentioned above, you are not modifying the input to the function. You could do the following:

```
def insertionSort(alist):
    blist = []

    for line in alist:
        line = list(map(int, line.split()))

        for index in range(2, len(line)):
            currentvalue = line[index]
            position = index

            while position>1 and line[position-1]>currentvalue:
                line[position]=line[position-1]
                position = position-1

            line[position]=currentvalue

        blist.append(line)

    return blist

blist = insertionSort(alist)
print(blist)
```

Alternatively, modify `alist` "in-place":

```
def insertionSort(alist):
    for k, line in enumerate(alist):
        line = list(map(int, line.split()))

        for index in range(2, len(line)):
            currentvalue = line[index]
            position = index

            while position>1 and line[position-1]>currentvalue:
                line[position]=line[position-1]
                position = position-1

            line[position]=currentvalue

        alist[k] = line


insertionSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Comment: Note that modifying in-place is usually unexpected; if you do this you should clearly say so in your function's docstring.

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell, While I do not disagree with you, I am not going to write docstrings for this piece of code. Sorry...